# Unexpected string equality results

Tags: ocaml, equality

I have some OCaml code:

```ml
let (&>) : ('x -> 'y) -> ('y -> 'z) -> ('x -> 'z) =
   fun g f x -> x |> g |> f

let soi x = string_of_int x
let sof x = string_of_float x
let fos x = float_of_string x
let ios x = int_of_string x

let clear_int = ios &> soi

let is_int_clear (x: string) = 
  let targ = clear_int x in
  let _ = print_endline x in
  let _ = print_endline targ in
  x == targ

let ccc = is_int_clear "123"

let scc = if ccc then "succ" else "fail"

let () = print_endline scc
```

I think `"123"` should be equal to `"123"` but output this:

```
123
123
fail
```

`"123"` was not equal `"123"`.

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: Style note: when you are aliasing functions in this example, examples like `let soi x = string_of_int x` can be witten as `let soi = string_of_int` but even then, it's questionable whether this _helps_ or actually just makes your code slightly more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault in your logic lies in using `==` which tests for physical equality. This is checking that the two strings reside at the same location in memory.

You wanted to use `=` which tests for structural equality: whether the two values contain the same information.

The change is *very* simple.

```
let is_int_clear (x: string) = 
  let targ = clear_int x in
  let _ = print_endline x in
  let _ = print_endline targ in
  x = targ
```